# IBAction Sender

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Everything works fine until I'm trying to pass [sender duration] to int dur. It works with TAG but not with my own var. I have tryed both INT and NSinteger for durationSpell.
What I'm trying to do is:
I have 10 different buttons that triggers spawnShoot, all with different durations. I want to get the duration from the button that was clicked.

```
@interface ClassUI : NSObject {

    CCMenuItemImage *button;
    CCSprite *shot;
    int durationSpell;
}
-----------------
    ClassUI *spellshealP1 = [[ClassUI alloc]init];

        spellshealP1.button = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"smallHeal.png" selectedImage:@"healempty.png" target:self selector:@selector(spawnShoot:)];

        spellshealP1.button.tag = 101;
        spellshealP1.durationSpell = 10;

CCMenu *player1menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:spellshealP1.button, spellbighealP1.button, spellcureP1.button, spellfocusP1.button, spellpoisonP1.button, spellbfBallP1.button, spellsfBallP1.button, nil];
player1menu.position = ccp(MoveMenuInXP1, (768/2) - (numberOfButtons*buttonSize/2) + buttonSize/2);
[self addChild:player1menu];
-----------------            
        -(IBAction)spawnShoot:(id)sender{
           int tag = [sender tag]; 
           int dur = [sender durationSpell];
        }
```

Comment: The durationSpell doesn't get added anywhere to the button (sender)...

Comment: What is the class of `sender`?  (i.e. `NSLog(@"%@", sender);`)

Comment: You set the `durationSpell` on `spellcureP1` but try to get it from the sender which is `spellshealP1`

Comment: updated the question, sorry for not being clear. :) Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the problem here is: the sender isn't `spellSheal`, but `spellSheal.button`.
So you're trying to get `spellSheal.button.durationSpell`, but in fact it is `spellSheal.durationSpell` ...

So, the best way to do this would be to let ClassUI inherit from CCMenuItemImage.
Here's how I would do it:

```
@interface ClassUI : CCMenuItemImage {
  CCSprite *shot;
  int durationSpell;
}
-----------------
ClassUI* spellshealP1 = [ClassUI itemFromNormalImage:@"smallHeal.png" selectedImage:@"healempty.png" target:self selector:@selector(spawnShoot:)];
spellshealP1.tag = 101;
spellshealP1.durationSpell = 10;
-----------------            
-(IBAction)spawnShoot:(id)sender{
  int tag = [sender tag]; 
  int dur = [sender durationSpell];
}
```

Comment: Hi m8, thanks for your answer. It did not work but thanks for clearing up how the sender works, alot of help. :) I'm new to this, only 2 moth of programming behind me.
I think i have to figure out another way to create what i'm trying to do. I have alot of buttons and alot of spells but i only want to make one action to exe the spell.

Comment: Okay, can you describe what exactly goes wrong? Do you get a compiler or runtime error?

Comment: I get: 'CCnode' may not respond to 'duration'

Comment: Try this: `int dur = [(ClassUI*)[sender parent] durationSpell];`

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to load the button or it's parent with mySpell parameters. Than I want to get the parameters from the button that was clicked. button1 = duration, button2 = duration. If I can get the value, "duration", from sender i can just apply it to the "player". I have loads of buttons and spell parameters so it would speed things up :)

Comment: Yes, I see. But you've tried the code I've mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: i got this error:
reason: '-[CCMenu durationSpell]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Well, sorry for the wrong suggestions above but I've now edited my answer to hopefully a much better solution